# Installing build-essential fails in Docker

Tags: docker, 18.04

Basically I have:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y software-properties-common ca-certificates wget curl ssh

RUN apt install -y build-essential
```

Which ends up in:

```
...

Get:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libalgorithm-merge-perl all 0.08-3 [12.0 kB]
Get:49 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libfile-fcntllock-perl amd64 0.22-3build2 [33.2 kB]
Get:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 manpages-dev all 4.15-1 [2217 kB]
Fetched 44.2 MB in 3s (15.0 MB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-19.20_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
The command '/bin/sh -c apt install -y build-essential' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Are there some broken packages now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved this by giving `--no-cache` to Docker.